# Ionic2 / Angular2 MailChimp API GET response

Tags: php, angular, ionic2, mailchimp

Okey so I've got a little problem with MailChimp response. So here is the thing.

I want to check the status of the subscribed user. I have the PHP code which is works fine and i have the code which is also works fine so I get the response BUT I can't use the response after it. So here is the codes:

I have a MailService provider which contain this function:

```
postCheck(post: {email: string}): Observable<any>{
    const email = JSON.stringify(post);
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-urlencoded');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8100/getapi', email, {
      headers: headers
    }).map(res => {
          console.log(res.json())
          return res.json(); //add this line
       });
  }
```

In the main page I have this function:

```
sendCheck(email: string){
      this.mailservice.postCheck({email: email})
      .subscribe(
        response => this.response = response.status,
        error => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

In the main page html when i call `<p>{{ response }}</p>` it write out 'pending' or 'subscribed'. But after it when I try `console.log(this.response);` it write out nothing so in the code I can't really do the checking.

Comment: How does your response actually look like? And what is your expected output? And where do you try and console.log the response?

Comment: This response is is only the status data from the json so its only shows that text. so it is only shows 'subscribed','pending' etc in `<p>{{ response }}</p>`. I expect / want a string(I tried JSON.stringify) so I can check the status with a simple if statement. I tried log out everywhere in the .ts file.

Comment: Maybe not still understanding but *status*, do you mean like the response status, e.g `200`? Because now you are trying to display a property `status` in your response. If you want the status of response, you should do just `.map(res => res)` and then you can subscribe to `response.status`

Comment: Hmm. I actually did the .map(res => res) in the postCheck function and the subscribe thing in the sendCheck function didn't I? I try to explain better what I need. If I know it right when this two function is working it gives me back a JSON file in the response and I want the value of the status from that JSON file which can be "subscribed", "pending" etc. And in the end when I get all of these data I just want to check the status with a simple if statement like: `if(this.status == "subscribed"){something happen}`

Comment: Okay I think I might understand now what you want to do... meaning, do something after your response has arrived. Hold on a second and I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather, you want to do something with your response after the data has arrived. This you need to do inside the subscription, to ensure that the data is available. So something like this:

```
sendCheck(email: string){
  this.mailservice.postCheck({email: email})
  .subscribe(response => { 
     this.response = response.status;
     // here the value has been set to response, so do what you want
     this.doSomethingWithResponse();
  )};
}

doSomethingWithResponse() {
  if(this.response == 'subscribed') {
     // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: It works!! Thank you so much you saved my life. I tried to figure this out for 2 weeks now.

Comment: No problem, you are very welcome, glad I could help! :)