# Angular 2 Http request with Observables. How to process data with .subscribe

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm writing a web app with angular 2 and have a API based on nodejs/express.

I've already got authentication up and running and I now want to query data from the API with is working fine.

The API gets its information from a remote server and sends a json array along the lines of: `{ "option1": "value1", "option2", "value2", ... }` and here is where my trouble starts.  I can fetch the data without problems and print them in my console via angular with `this.apiService.get('serverinfo').subscribe(console.log(response));` but can't access them anywhere else even if I try to write into a variable correctly.

Here's my code so far:

api.service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, Response, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
//import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class Data {
}

// Import RxJs required methods
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/delay';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';

@Injectable()
export class ApiService {
  private getUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/get/';

  constructor(private http: Http) { }


  get(what): Observable<Data[]> {
    var token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('id_token'));
    return this.http
      .get(this.getUrl + what + '?token=' + token.token)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
//response => response.json() as Data[]
  }

  // localStorage.setItem('id_token', JSON.stringify({ token: body.token }));
  private extractData(res: Response) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body || {};
  }

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    // In a real world app, you might use a remote logging infrastructure
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
  }
}
```

overview.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService, Data } from '../services/api.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview.component.scss']
})
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(public apiService: ApiService) { }

  data: Data = {};

  ngOnInit() { this.getData() }
  getData() {
    this.apiService.get('serverinfo').subscribe(console.log(response)); // Logs data correctly to console
    /*.subscribe( response => this.data = response )*/ // Can't access data from this one
   console.log(this.data)
  }
}
```

I think it may be cause of the Data type and I saw examples were all options from the data were preconfigured there but I can't really do that here because I have really big object and these won't always be the same structure.

Comment: Would this be an async problem, whereas you need to do the stuff you need to do inside the subscription... in that case, there is plenty of questions and answers about that here, check one of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42886437/6294072

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You data is an object: `data: Data = {};` But in your get you return an array: `get(what): Observable<Data[]>`

Try this: `data: Data[] = [];`

Comment: thanks this worked. I already tried it with 'data: Data[]' but it didn't work then.